# How to work Flurry with debug mode on Android.?

Tags: android, flurry

I am using Flurry analytics for tracking apps behaviours. A lot error is thrown while App is developed, I can find and fix that error on Android console however these errors are uploaded to Flurry Console and They are confusing me.

I used below codes to intercept these but This time Flurry doesn't work at all.

```
if( !BuildConfig.DEBUG ){
            // configure Flurry
            FlurryAgent.setLogEnabled( false );
            FlurryAgent.init( this, MY_FLURRY_APIKEY );
            formValidationHelper = new FormValidationHelper();
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

What your code is doing is preventing Flurry initialization in debug mode, which, I assume, is not what you want to do. If you want the SDK to work in debug mode, you should still call `FlurryAgent.init(Context, String)`.

There are several ways to do this. The definite way is to create another Flurry API key for your debug development and use your main API key for release.

If you want to remove Flurry crash-reporting altogether, you can do that using `FlurryAgent.setCaptureUncaughtExceptions(boolean)`. The default for this setting is true so Flurry will send crash information to the dashboard. You could, of course, leave it as default when releasing your app, but can turn it off during development.

Here's a snippet showing what I mean about using different API keys and disabling crash-report in debug mode:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    FlurryAgent.setLogEnabled(true);
    FlurryAgent.setCaptureUncaughtExceptions(false);
    FlurryAgent.init(this, FLURRY_DEBUG_KEY);
    // Other debug setup
} else {
    FlurryAgent.setLogEnabled(false);
    FlurryAgent.init(this, FLURRY_RELEASE_KEY);
    // Other release setup
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Should I create a new project to create a new Flurry Apı key ?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to create a new project. If your main project is called "X Android app", for example, you can name the new project "X Android app test"

Comment: So, If I dont't want to create a new Flurry Apı key, does that code block work ? ======> 
if ( BuildConfig.DEBUG ) {
            FlurryAgent.setLogEnabled( true );
            FlurryAgent.setCaptureUncaughtExceptions( false );
        } else {
            FlurryAgent.setLogEnabled( false );
        }

        FlurryAgent.init( this, MY_FLURRY_APIKEY );

Comment: No, you'll still need to initialize Flurry in debug mode so you'll call `FlurryAgent.init(this, MY_FLURRY_APIKEY)` in debug mode. So it will be the same thing as what I wrote above, just with the same API key in both places.